# Auto acknowledge failed with nRF 24L01+ and Arduino

Tags: remote-control, rf

My transceivers are running fine. I've written a few code and got them running. Then I decided to check the auto acknowledgement feature wherein we can return data back to the sender WITHOUT manually changing the radio modes on both units. But I find that the serial monitor always shows "failed to transmit". Why is this happening, because otherwise they work fine?

I am using maniacbug's RF24master library.

The Tx code is:

```
#include<SPI.h>
#include<nRF24L01.h>
#include<RF24.h>

int msg[1] = {1};
int rec[1] = {0};
bool stat = true;
RF24 radio(9,10);
const uint64_t pipe[1] = {0xF0F0F0F0E1LL};

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(57600);
  radio.begin();
  delay(1000);
  radio.setAutoAck(true);
  radio.enableAckPayload();
  radio.openWritingPipe(pipe[0]);
  radio.setRetries(15,15);
 }
void loop()
{
  if(stat)
  {
    radio.stopListening();
    bool ok = radio.write(msg,sizeof(msg));
    delay(100);
    if(ok)
    {Serial.println("transmitted successfully !!");}
    else
    {Serial.println("faileed to transmit");}
    msg[1]++;
    if(msg[1]>=200)
    {msg[1]=1;}
    stat = false;
    //delay(20);
  }
  if(!stat)
  {
    if(radio.isAckPayloadAvailable())
    {
      radio.read(rec,sizeof(rec));
      Serial.print("received ack payload is : ");
      Serial.println(rec[1]);
      stat = true;    
    }
  }

}
```

and the Rx part is:

```
#include<SPI.h>
#include<nRF24L01.h>
#include<RF24.h>
const uint64_t pipe = 0xF0F0F0F0E1LL;
RF24 radio(9,10);
int rec[1] = {0};
int ack[1] = {1};
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(57600);
  radio.begin();
  delay(100);
  radio.setAutoAck(true);
  radio.enableAckPayload();
  radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipe);
  radio.startListening();
  radio.setRetries(15,15);
}
void loop()
{
  if(radio.available())
  {
    Serial.println("payload available....");
    bool ok = radio.read(rec,sizeof(rec));
    if(ok)
    {
        Serial.println("message received !!");
        Serial.print("integer got is : ");
        Serial.println(rec[1]);
        radio.writeAckPayload(1,ack,sizeof(ack));
    }
    else
    {Serial.println("failed to receive the message");}
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that you need to provide the AckPayload before you receive a message, not after.

Comment: no,no we have to provide the ack payload after we receive a msg.my code is buggy.i wrote a new and better one and it is working !!! btw thanks for checking out the ques!!

Comment: If you found a solution to your question, please post it as an answer and accept it, so that people who have a similar problem an benefit from your experience.

Comment: my blog is up and running. the auto ack code and discussion is here http://shantamraj.wordpress.com/2014/07/19/exploring-the-auto-ack-feature-of-the-transceiver/ @jfpoilpret .

Comment: @jfpoilpret Please post the answer and accept it here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this long abandoned question because the issue has never been clearly stated, and the asker seems to have long since found their own solution and published it on their blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that you have to do the following -

```
if ( radio.available() ) { // make sure the read will succeed
radio.writeAckPayload( 1, buf, len ); // prep the ack payload
radio.read( &got_time, sizeof(unsigned long) ); // also shunts out ack payload
}
```

So your program finally becomes -

```
#include<SPI.h>
#include<nRF24L01.h>
#include<RF24.h>
int msg[1] = {1};
int rec[1] = {5};
bool stat = true;
RF24 radio(9,10);
const uint64_t pipe[1] = {0xF0F0F0F0E1LL};

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(57600);
  radio.begin();
  delay(100);
  radio.setAutoAck(true);
  radio.enableAckPayload();
  radio.enableDynamicPayloads();
  radio.stopListening();
  radio.openWritingPipe(pipe[0]);
  radio.setRetries(15,15);
 }
void loop()
{
if(stat)
{
    if(radio.write(msg,sizeof(msg)))
    {
      Serial.print( msg[0] );
      Serial.println("...tx success");
      if(radio.isAckPayloadAvailable())
      {
        radio.read(rec,sizeof(int));
        Serial.print("received ack payload is : ");
        Serial.println(rec[0]);
      }
      else
      {
        stat = false; //doing this completely shuts down the transmitter if an ack payload is not received !!
        Serial.println("status has become false so stop here....");
      }
      msg[0]+=3;;
    if(msg[0]>=100)
    {msg[0]=1;}
    }
 }
}
```

And the RX part becomes -

```
#include<SPI.h>
#include<nRF24L01.h>
#include<RF24.h>
const uint64_t pipe[1]= {0xF0F0F0F0E1LL};
RF24 radio(9,10);
int rec[1] = {2};
int red;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(57600);
  radio.begin();
  delay(100);
  radio.setAutoAck(true);
  radio.enableAckPayload();
  radio.enableDynamicPayloads();
  radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipe[0]);
  radio.startListening();
  radio.setRetries(15,15);
}
void loop()
{
  if ( radio.available() ) {
    radio.writeAckPayload( 1, rec, sizeof(int) );
    radio.read( &red,sizeof(red) );rec[0]+=2;
    Serial.print("integer got is : ");
    Serial.println(red);
}
}
```

Know more about it at the following pages - 
https://shantamraj.wordpress.com/2014/07/19/exploring-the-auto-ack-feature-of-the-transceiver/
https://shantamraj.wordpress.com/2014/11/30/auto-ack-completely-fixed/